# toolbar не влазят иконки

Tags: android, toolbar

Стрелка не подгоняется под toolbar. Иконка подгоняется но только сверху и с низу как видно по сторонам зазор большой. Собственно как внутренние элементы сделать `match_parant`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <!--android:visibility="gone"-->


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@color/status_bar_orange"
        />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gcm.bogdan.toolbar.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- **** Place Your Content Here **** -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>

        <!-- **** Place Your Content Here **** -->
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="5dp"
              android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo);
        mToolbar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mToolbar.setSubtitle("SubTittle");
        mToolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLogo));
        mToolbar.setTitle("Tittle");
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
        mToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription("NavigationContentDescription");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит ваш `R.drawable.ic_back` большого размера. 
Посмотрите [документацию по иконкам.](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)

Если не хотите возиться с нарезкой, [вот здесь](http://shreyasachar.com/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) можете нарезать иконок. 
Еще [от google](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components) для популярных редакторов.

Comment: То есть все идет к тому что картинки надо резать самому под разные разрешения? А чтобы само подгоняло ни как? Например иконка app размер меняет почему кнопка back этого не делает?

Comment: Да. Надо резать самому под разные разрешения. Так уж задумано. Android asset studio в помощь. То что иконка app размер у вас меняет не дает абсолютно никакой гарантии, что это будет работать на другой платформе с другой версией андроида...

Answer (score 1):

Эти иконки подгоняться не будут. Они должны быть строго определенных размеров. Общая ширина-высота должна быть 32dp, а видимая часть (если обрезать пустые поля) - 24dp. Все это (и многое многое другое) описано в [Material design guide](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons)